# Best way to stop Docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Sometimes it happens to me that I have Dockerfiles that run forever to build. What would be the best way to stop such builds? If I just hit `ctrl + C` the build will stop but everything that was pulled up to that point will remain and I won't be able to remove it, because the image didn't finished building which means I can't delete the image. Correct?

If anyone is getting into similar situations, please advise.

Comment: Whatever was built already will be "dangling" images, which will show up as `<none>` in the `docker images` listing, and `docker system prune` and similar commands will delete them.  The specific `RUN` command that got aborted shouldn't leave anything behind.  C-c is still right.

Comment: you're right, i noticed ```<none>```s after running ```docker image ls```